# Rails and React : TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

i am making Post system with React on my Rails project.
But when i try to render Posts in my Home page i get this error:

> React::ServerRendering::PrerenderError in HomeController#index
>   Encountered error "TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined" when prerendering PostsList with {"posts":null} React.createClass.render ((execjs):19669:38)

My code is the above:

```
posts_list.js.jsx:
var PostsList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { posts: this.props.initialPosts };
    },

    render: function() {
        var posts = this.state.posts.map(function(post) {
            return  <Post key={post.id} post={post} />;
        });

        return (
            <div className="posts">
                {posts}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

post.js.jsx

```
var Post = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="post">
                <PostTitle post={this.props.post} />
                <PostBody post={this.props.post} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var PostTitle = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="post-header">
                <h2>{this.props.post.title}</h2>
                <div className="post-meta">
                    By {this.props.post.user_id} - {this.props.post.created_at}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var PostBody = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="post-contents">
                {this.props.post.body}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

and index.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3> Posts Feed </h3>
        <%= react_component('PostsList', {initialPosts: @posts }, {prerender: true}) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

post_controller.rb

```
def index
        @posts = Post.all
        @user = current_user
end
```

when i use {initialPosts: Post.All } its works, but when i use with @posts , its not

any ideas why happening that? i have done posts into the site and @posts is not empty.

Comment: its not working like this too.. when i use { initialPosts: Post.all  } its works, but otherwise not..

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found what was wrong, i was rendering react in home layout, but the @posts was defined in posts controller instead of home controller.